# Which programming language is mostly used for DevOPs and Why?

Tags: automation, devops

I am about to start working on DevOps stuff. I have worked on many programming languages like C#, Python and Ruby. I have no idea which language should be used for automation scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this questions.
Being a devops engineer, its your responsibility to automate pipeline and publishing work(docker images).I prefer python for automation as it can be easily understood, written and comes installed with linux based distros.